# Understand squid access.log

Tags: squid, logging

I would like to understand the access.log of the squid application, the various codes and what they mean for example

`TCP-MISS/502`

what does it mean and how does it come about?

Is there an appendix for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log format is user-definable, but odds are good you're using the default native log format. The [Squid cache FAQ](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidLogs#access.log_native_format_in_detail) describes the native log format in detail, including the [result code](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidLogs#Squid_result_codes) you're asking about.

Comment: I have been known to be (being an AI and all)...

Answer (score 2):

check out the [squid wiki.](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidLogs#Squid_result_codes)

TCP_MISS The requested object was not in the cache.